# Regex for matching a string that can not have some characters or a substring

Tags: regex, jsonschema

I am trying to add a routing time (during REST API modeling) regexp validation for the Mongo DB collection name as per [Mongo DB specification](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restriction-on-Collection-Names) (mongo 3.6).

It says (copy pasting from the above doc):

```
Restriction on Collection Names
Collection names should begin with 

 - an underscore or a letter character

and cannot:

 - contain the $.
 - be an empty string (e.g. "").
 - contain the null character.
 - begin with the system. prefix. (Reserved for internal use.)
```

Another restriction (sort of), I have is: it's for JSON Schema validation as per [json-schema supported subset of the regexp](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html#regular-expressions). It's not the full of regexp (e.g. I can not use \d, \w (or I can not able to use \b<...>\b).

With this, so far, I am able to do the other parts *without* the

```
- begin with the system. prefix. (Reserved for internal use.)
```

section.

Here is my regexp as of now in my REST API JSON schema (refer to the pattern below):

```
'collectionName': {
                description: "foo bar",
                type: 'string',
                minLength: 1,
                maxLength: 120,
                pattern: '(^[a-zA-Z0-9_][^$ \\0]*$)',  <== this one.
                example: 'MyCollection',
            },
```

To clarify further with a few examples:

1. It **should not match** something like -collection, but **should match** _collection or collec-tion
2. The stings contains a space or $ - **should not match** (e.g. collec tion, collec$$tion)
3. Something like this **should match**: systemCollection
4. This **should not match**: system.collection  // as system. prefix is reserved for Mongo.

Trying my best to clarify the question to the best possible way I can.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Pradip

Comment: Could you clarify what is not working as expected please? I can't see an example of input that you expect to fail validation but is not.

Comment: The whole '- begin with the system. prefix.' rule is not there in the regex. Means: the point #4 I called out earlier, that should not match. 
Please refer this section: "To clarify further with a few examples".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a negative lookahead.

`^(?!system\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_][^$ \\0]*$`

> `(?!...)` Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures
> that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters. - regex101.com

This is the same in PCRE as ECMAScript. MongoDB uses PCRE for its regex, so I assume the same is true for regex inside JSON Schema for MongoDB.

Here's an example working with your sample data test cases https://regex101.com/r/CHu6lz/1

I've only covered the case you stated of not starting with `system.`. You'll need to extend the regex to add your extra cases, but it should be clear how to do that now you know about negative lookaheads.

You'll also need to escape the regex for use in JSON, as per comments on this answer, and as you have done already.

Comment: You're totally right. I didn't cover all the use cases. It would have been easier if OP had given a list of "should pass" and "should fail" like I asked. I'll update my answer to show it isn't the full solution.

Comment: Glad I could help. regex101.com is one of my go to regex tools!

Comment: Indeed .. this regex101 is cool. It's even showing the match groups also (). Thank You for the pointer @Relequestual.
Much appreciated.